# UITextView does not update

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextview

I am trying to update the text of a UITextView programmatically. This was working a couple of days ago, but can't tell why it has stopped.

Creating the UITextView

```
self.recordInfoTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrame];    
self.recordInfoTextView.editable=NO;
self.recordInfoTextView.scrollEnabled=NO;
self.recordInfoTextView.multipleTouchEnabled=NO;
self.recordInfoTextView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;  
self.recordInfoTextView.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.recordInfoTextView.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
self.recordInfoTextView.text=@"Record 1 of 1";
[self.recordInfoTextView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)];

[self.view addSubview:recordInfoTextView];
```

The UITextView appears with the initial string value. However, it does not update here:

```
-(void)displayContentInTextView {
    self.recordInfoTextView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Record %d of %d", currentIndex+1, [idNumberArray count]];
    NSLog(@"displayContentInWebView: Record %d of %d", currentIndex+1, [idNumberArray count]);
}

-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        if (currentIndex < ([idNumberArray count]-1)) {
            currentIndex++;
            recordID = [[idNumberArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex] intValue];
            [self displayContentInTextView];
        }
    } else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex--;
            recordID = [[idNumberArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex] intValue];
            [self displayContentInTextView];
        }
    }
}
```

The log shows that displayContentInWebView is called appropriately and the expected information is sent to the log, however, the UITextView does not update, but continues to display the initial text.

Thanks in advance! Tim

Comment: also, tried adding [self.recordInfoTextView setNeedsDisplay]; but that didn't help.

Comment: Check to see if the `recordInfoTextView` is null

Comment: Changed NSLOG to NSLog(@"displayContentInWebView: Record %d of %d (%@)", currentIndex+1, [idNumberArray count], self.recordInfoTextView); and placed it before the text change. The output first time is displayContentInWebView: Record 5 of 158 ((null)), but after swiping, I get displayContentInWebView: Record 6 of 158 (<UITextView: 0x4e33030; frame = (10 376; 300 30); text = 'Record 1 of 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e33240>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>). So at that point it looks like the object is set but doesn't update.

Comment: Where do you create your UITextView?  Also, is any of this running in a background thread?

Comment: Originally, I called the creation function from ViewDidLoad of the parent class. I moved it to the child class and it now appears to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the question is already answered but:
you can replace all `self.recordInfoTextView` with just `recordInfoTextView` it should still work and hey, less code :)